# Regular expression to parse html links

Tags: regex

I have this html with this type of snippit below all over:

```
<li><label for="summary">Summary:</label></li>
<li class="in">
    <textarea class="ta" id="summary" name="summary" rows="4" cols="10" tabindex="4">
        ${fieldValue(bean: book, field: 'summary')}</textarea> 

    <a href="#" class="tt">
        <img src="<g:createLinkTo dir='images/buttons/' file='icon.gif'/>" alt="Help icon for the summary field">
        <span class="tooltip">
            <span class="top"></span>
            <span class="middle">Help text for summary</span>
            <span class="bottom"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to pull off the alt value and the text between XXXX and replace the a tag with the code below.

This is my stab at the reg ex

```
<a href="#" class="tt">.*alt="(.*)".*<span class="middle">(.*)<\/span><\/a>
```

Output with the callbacks

```
<ebs:cssToolTip alt="$1" text="$2"/>
```

I tried it out on http://rubular.com/ and it does not quite work. Any suggestions

Comment: Added whitespace for readability

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ensure your regexp isn't greedily picking up characters - use ".*?" rather than straight ".*".

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "it does not quite work"? How does it fail?

A suggestion (not tested your regexp): note that `*` is a greedy operator, so `.*` is rarely a good idea because it may match a lot more than what you intended.

Try:

```
<a href="#" class="tt">.*alt="([^"]*)".*<span class="middle">([^"]*)<\/span><\/a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Think i solved it by getting an idea from another stackoverflow question

```
<a href="#" class="tt">.*alt="([^"]*)".*<span class="middle">([^<]*).*<\/a>
```

This seems to work on the http://rubular.com/ site

Comment: This achieves the same as .*? - for example: `alt="(.*?)"` will match everything up to the next ", but `alt="(.*)"` will match everything to last "

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://rubular.com/regexes/8434

You were facing two potential problems.  First, without adding the //m option, '.' will not match newline characters.  Second, you were using greedy matching.  Adding the '*?' makes it better.

```
/<a href="#" class="tt">.*?alt="([^"]*)">.*?<span class="middle">(.*?)<\/span>/m
```